# where is the best place to declare variable in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on android team, and
writing codes, I got a question.
When declaring some variables,
I write the variable at the top of class.
For example like this

```
class Test {
  val num1: Int = 0
  val num2: Int = 0

  fun getNum1Sqrt() = num1 * num1
  fun getNum2Sqrt() = num2 * num2
}
```

But I found someone write codes like this

```
class Test {
  val num1: Int = 0
  fun getNum1Sqrt() = num1 * num1

  val num2: Int = 0
  fun getNum2Sqrt() = num2 * num2
}
```

I want to fit the convention.
Where is the best place to declare variable?
It's only up to the team convention?

Comment: these are not variables but properties

Comment: I think there's a good deal of leeway in this — personal taste and judgement are probably more important than slavish adherence to some oversimplified rule. What you have to ask in each case is: What would be easiest to read? What's most logical? Where would someone _expect_ to find this member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is correct.

From kotlin conventions:[Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#class-layout)

Class layout:

The contents of a class should go in the following order:

1. Property
2. declarations and initializer blocks
3. Secondary constructors
4. Method declarations Companion object

Comment: thanks for answer, is that same to place the variable at the top in function?

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for variables inside functions